# Is there a standard CSS margin/padding/etc. for HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, webkit

I believe WordPress does something like this, they use a [CSS reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), then manually apply a global margin for each HTML element (to increase browser compatibility). I'm looking for something like this, but without the WordPress specific elements.

On a similar note, is there a default stylesheet that WebKit uses that I can access?

Comment: The reset stylesheet you linked to doesn't have any "WordPress specific elements."

Comment: Why do you think WordPress uses a reset? And what "WordPress specific elements" are you talking about?

Comment: You mean you want to know all the default attributes of all HTML elements that are defined BY DEFAULT by webkit-Browser ?

Comment: Yes but I want my WebKit browser specific attributes for all browsers visiting my site.
And the stylesheet was supposed to be an example of a CSS reset sheet. 
By WordPress specific elements I meant css classes like post, entry-title etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using normalize.css as opposed to a reset.css; checking their demo seems to indicate this includes standards for form elements:

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1):

a quick google search turned up this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and this: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ among others

Answer (score 1):

I generally use [YUI Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) for this. [YUI Base CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/base/) can complement Reset by applying a style foundation for common HTML elements that is consistent across A-grade browsers. YUI is from Yahoo and hence enjoys good support and is presumably more reliable than other similar CSS frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

default Chrome WebKit http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

here's a butt load more default user agent style sheets
http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard CSS `margin` etc. that I know of...

That's one of the reasons why a reset stylesheet is necessary.  No one sets the same styles and most browsers have different defaults.

For me, once I reset `margin` and `padding` on most elements, I usually make the `margin` around `1em` for `p`, `h1-h5`, etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?